# how can i use sed to remove a ] special character

Tags: sed

how can i use sed in a special way to remove apart of a special character

```
sed s/^}$//g > file
```

doesn't do anything, I'm trying to remove the beginning of every line up to the bracket, so that this line

```
Aug 09 19:46:15 inspire NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1533861975.9201] dhcp4 (wlp3s0b1): state changed unknown
```

looks like this

```
dhcp4 (wlp3s0b1): state changed unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would expect that to work, however if you want to match (and remove) the longest string ending in `]` and its trailing space, you can use `sed 's/.*] //'`

Ex.

```
echo 'Aug 09 19:46:15 inspire NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1533861975.9201] dhcp4 (wlp3s0b1): state changed unknown' | 
  sed 's/.*] //'
dhcp4 (wlp3s0b1): state changed unknown
```

---

FYI, `^}$` would match `}` on a line by its own (i.e. anchored to both the start of the line `^` and to the end of the line `$`)

Comment: You're a God, Thank you, why doesn't sed 's/^*]$//g' work, doesn't that say beginning with anything up to ] the end